# Parsing data that looks like a csv but it is not?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse a file that looks like a csv file but its not. It is separated by commas however, there is a space after each comma. Also there is no headers and has different length of rows.

Here is an example if I open the file in a .txt format I get something like this:

```
FUD, speed, time, heading, offsets
MUD, speed, time, heading, offsets, error
CLA, head, time, speed, offset, error, errorfix
MUD, speed, time, heading, offsets, error
MUD, speed, time, heading, offsets, error
FUD, speed, time, heading, offsets
CLA, head, time, speed, offset, error, errorfix
CLA, head, time, speed, offset, error, errorfix
(note head, time, offset and all those after the first column are all values.)
```

Now I have tried this.

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_csv('data.csv', headers = None)
MUD = df[df[0]=='MUD'].values.tolist()
```

However, I got this error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 3, saw 18
```

When I did a google search for the error it was suggested that I should use

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

However, that gave me an error of:

```
expected 10 fields, saw 15.
```

I am trying to make a panda list of every instance of MUD I see, so later I can just do something like this:

```
newMUD = MUD[4]/100
```

Eventually I would have something like this:

```
print (MUD)
MUD, 12, 1, 5, 1, 1
MUD, 13, 2, 3, 2, 0
MUD, 12, 3, 5, -2, 0
MUD, 4, 4, 3, -3, 1
```

Sample of my data

```
NKF1, 447526092, -3.08, 0.01, 175.83, -0.02133949, 0.03264881, -0.06251871, 0, -28.93325, 26.49632, -0.1290034, 0.07, -0.02, 0.14
NKF2, 447526092, -26, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 255, 55, 341, 0, 0, 0, 0
NKF3, 447526092, -0.01, 0.06, 0.12, -0.04, -0.08, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, -0.73, 0.00
NKF4, 447526092, 0.03, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0002261061, 0, 0, 0, 16, 9023, 0, 1
NKF5, 447526092, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00, 0.50, 0.003602755, 0.01431285, 0.02802294
NKF6, 447526092, -2.66, -0.98, 187.53, -0.06789517, -0.2714562, -0.1189714, 0, -28.96132, 26.25431, -0.2784806, 0.00, 0.36, -0.49
NKF7, 447526092, 21, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 258, 55, 338, 0, 0, 0, 0
NKF8, 447526092, -0.04, -0.20, 0.07, -0.04, -0.23, -0.17, 0, 0, 0, 10.83, 0.00
NKF9, 447526092, 0.04, 0.03, 0.01, 0.12, 0.00, 0.000866859, 0, 0, 0, 16, 9023, 0, 1
AHR2, 447526241, -3.12, -0.42, 176.43, 418.84, 34.3167522, -118.4068499
POS, 447526306, 34.3167515, -118.406853, 419.03, 0.2784806
IMU, 447545009, -0.09418038, 0.1740572, -0.05483108, 0.6083156, 0.2225795, -9.380787, 0, 0, 52.99446, 1, 1
IMU2, 447545009, -0.09127176, 0.1908958, -0.06220703, 0.524766, 0.3107446, -8.754621, 0, 0, 56.125, 1, 1
SONR, 447545584, 0, 0, 0, 0
RFND, 447545593, 0.00, 0.00
IMU, 447565482, -0.08753563, 0.1228692, -0.04508965, 0.6137247, -0.01505011, -9.579732, 0, 0, 53.0831, 1, 1
IMU2, 447565482, -0.08944235, 0.139776, -0.05096832, 0.4677677, 0.03778861, -9.214079, 0, 0, 55.875, 1, 1
GPS, 447565911, 4, 246769200, 1920, 14, 0.70, 34.3167523, -118.4068497, 418.91, 0.05656854, 135, -0.16, 1
GPA, 447565911, 1.11, 0.73, 1.04, 0.29, 1, 447565
SONR, 447566084, 0, 0, 0, 0
RFND, 447566093, 0.00, 0.00
ATT, 447566114, 0.00, -2.88, 0.00, -0.62, 0.00, 187.41, 0.02, 0.01
PIDR, 447566125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
PIDP, 447566135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
PIDY, 447566145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
PIDS, 447566155, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
NKF1, 447566164, -3.30, 0.35, 175.70, -0.02778457, 0.03493549, -0.04115778, 0, -28.9337, 26.49665, -0.1338468, 0.07, -0.02, 0.14
NKF2, 447566164, -26, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 255, 55, 341, 0, 0, 0, 0
NKF3, 447566164, -0.01, 0.06, 0.12, -0.04, -0.08, -0.11, 0, 0, 0, -0.73, 0.00
NKF4, 447566164, 0.03, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0002256641, 0, 0, 0, 16, 9023, 0, 1
NKF5, 447566164, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00, 0.50, 0.003267812, 0.01763795, 0.02970827
NKF6, 447566164, -2.88, -0.62, 187.40, -0.07544779, -0.2697962, -0.09678251, 0, -28.96231, 26.2515, -0.2831134, 0.00, 0.36, -0.49
NKF7, 447566164, 21, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 258, 55, 338, 0, 0, 0, 0
NKF8, 447566164, -0.04, -0.20, 0.07, -0.04, -0.23, -0.25, 0, 0, 0, 10.83, 0.00
NKF9, 447566164, 0.04, 0.03, 0.01, 0.12, 0.00, 0.00086712, 0, 0, 0, 16, 9023, 0, 1
AHR2, 447566373, -3.34, -0.07, 176.32, 418.84, 34.3167522, -118.4068497
POS, 447566396, 34.3167515, -118.406853, 419.04, 0.2831134
IMU, 447587271, -0.08603665, 0.071096, -0.03380377, 0.5931511, -0.07432687, -9.615693, 0, 0, 53.0831, 1, 1
IMU2, 447587271, -0.08848803, 0.09229023, -0.04071644, 0.4688947, 0.01987415, -9.166938, 0, 0, 56.125, 1, 1
MAG, 447587700, -265, -77, 332, -115, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 447587691
MAG2, 447587700, -273, -29, 372, 77, -135, 38, 0, 0, 0, 1, 447587693
ARSP, 447587748, 2.969838, 4.424126, 38.22, -4.424126, 110.8502, 1
BARO, 447587789, -0.09136668, 97036.14, 55.03, -0.8952343, 447587, 0
CURR, 447587949, 16.91083, 0.6012492, 60.22538
```

Comment: Issue is likely the comma at the end of lines 3, 7, and 8 - not the space after each comma.

Comment: do you really need pandas or could that be done using python alone? what is your need?

Comment: @Billy Sorry, I didn't mean to add commas there, I went ahead and updated the first question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, I don't have to use panda, but I have tried this using csv and it became a mess. where if I want to add two columns together or multiply I had to do something like this newMUD = [x/1000 for x in MUD[2]] and if I wanted to have some complicated math functions this will be a pain in the ass to deal with. I just want to be able to type out a equation and replace the variable with MUD[2] or CLA[1]. So I was told panda is much better with that.

Comment: Well, this is not really a CSV file as you have a varying amount of columns. Just parse it line by line and convert it to a dataframe afterwards. Or just do the calculation in-place.

Comment: @filmor Could you elaborate a bit on the parsing part? I don't mind creating a file list for each row I don't have that many but would the result be easily manipulated for example I can do something like this t1= MUD[3] + CLA[3] ?

Comment: Could you maybe add an exemple of how your dataframe would look like? I'm having problems visualizing it because of the varying length

Comment: @JulienMarrec Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. It it just what I posted and repeated about couple of thousands time. Of course there is other rows of data but this was just a sample. If you mean by what exactly it looks like something like this. FUD, 23, 14, 10, -5

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to do calculations on the columns, using Pandas makes sense (didn't get that from the question). In that case it's sufficient to pass along the expected column names, such that the parser is not surprised by the changing amount of columns:

```
# Creates a list ["note", "head" ... ]
columns = "note head time speed offset error errorfix".split()

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=columns)

MUD = df.query("note == 'MUD'")

MUD["speed"] / 4
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I got an error first saying DtypeWarning: Columns (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False., when I added that, and tried to print (MUD), I got an empty dataframe.

Comment: Well then, I guess it's time for you to provide actual data :)

Comment: Check question I have add part of my data.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the lines as you create the dataframe with `from_records`. Here I use the `csv` module to create rows and discard the unwanted ones.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def data_reader(filename, rowname):
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        yield from (row[1:] for row in csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
            if row[0] == rowname)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader('testfile', 'MUD'))
print(df)
```

That's a bit risky - if non-MUD lines don't conform to standard csv rules, the reader may raise an error. Here is a more complicated version that limits the csv parser to the MUD lines

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def mud_reader(filename, rowname):
    rowname = rowname + ", "
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        yield from (row[len(rowname):] for row in csv.reader(
            (line for line in fp if line.startswith(rowname)),
            skipinitialspace=True))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mud_reader('testfile', 'MUD'))
print(df)
```

Comment: The first solution worked, though is there a more efficient way of writing it for all of them? since now I need to create a def for each (MUD, CAL, FUD.. and about 10 more) Also, I tried to do this MUD_TIME = MUD[1] /100 and I got a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int

Comment: The type error is a pandas thing. Depending on your data, you may find stripping the first column is enough (row[1:] for row in ...) because its a string but you may need to cast the data as its read in. Try the first, its easier!

Comment: You could add a parameter to name which record type for the scan and call it multiple times for the various values. It may be okay fast since after the first read, the file is likely cached by the operating system.

Comment: I am so confused by what you just said, I am sorry I am a bit slow could you elaborate with an example in your answer please?

Comment: I've updated to let the first column name be a parameter and trim it out of the dataframe.